# Dividing two numbers inside an if statement gives wrong output

Tags: c++

when i divide two numbers inside an if statement and check for a condition, if goes false even if it should be true

if a directly type (w/h) inside if instead of s it gives wrong output.

given this input

```
5
10 1
165 100
180 100
170 100
160 100
```

it should give 3,
but if i give (w/h) inside if instead of s it gives output as 1
I dont get it, if becomes false even though statement is true.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 long long n,c=0;


 cin>>n;
 while(n--)
 {
     long double w,h;
     cin>>w>>h;

     double s = w/h;
     if(s >=1.6 && s <=1.7) // if((w/h)>=1.6 &&(w/h)<=1.7) becomes false for w=170, h=100
     {
         c++;

     }
 }
 cout<<c;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that double is not precise! Calculations that in mathematics result in exactly 1.6 differ if calculated in double. *Necessarily*, as 1.6 itself cannot be represented exactly in double (1.6 is periodic in binary representation!). All the same for long double as well (solely precision is a bit higher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `if(s >=1.6 && s <=1.7) // if((w/h)>=1.6 &&(w/h)<=1.7) becomes false for w=170, h=100`

When you have `(w/h)<=1.7`, you are directly using the result of division of `170.0L` by `100.0L` (i.e. two numbers of type `long double`), which is, on x86 gcc, equal to the following number (closest representation of 1.7 in `long double`)

```
1.70000000000000000004336808689942017736029811203479766845703125
```

You are then comparing it with `1.7`, which is, when converted to actual value, approximated by the closest representable `double` (because the literal is of type `double`):

```
1.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

Of course, the former is greater than the latter, so you get `false`.

OTOH, when you assign the result of division to `s`, it is rounded to the type of `s`, i.e. `double`, and then you compare the equal numbers, which gives you `true`.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing different results because of mixing `double` and `long double`.

When you use:

```
if ( (w/h) >= 1.6 && (w/h) <= 1.7)
```

the  term `w/h` is of type `long double`. For comparison, `1.6` and `1.7` are promoted to `long double`.

If you want to see the same results, use:

```
 long double s = w/h;
 if ( s >= 1.6 && s <= 1.7 )
```

Having said that, it's best to compare floating point numbers with some tolerance.

```
 long double tolerenance = 1.0E-6; // I'm picking an aribtray number.
 long double s = w/h;
 if ( s >= (1.6 - tolerance) && s <= (1.7 + tolerance) )
```

Answer (score -3):

Was your original statement like this:

```
if( w/h >= 1.6 && w/h <= 1.7) {
```

then try wrapping the w/h like this:

```
if( (w/h) >= 1.6 && (w/h) <= 1.7) {
```